# Setting up Unity Smart Merge with Git and Meld for Unity 2019.3+

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, git-merge, meld

I looked everywhere for documentation on this matter with little to no success. Unity's own documentation is very much incomplete when it comes to this dynamic. I am here to provide you with the only way I've been able to get it to work. Of course I would appreciate feedback on how this could be done better, but as it stands now nearly all Google searches on this topic are 2 years old or older.

The Unity docs say to add the following to the `.git/config`:

```
[merge]
    tool = unityyamlmerge

[mergetool "unityyamlmerge"]
    trustExitCode = false
    cmd = '<path to UnityYAMLMerge>' merge -p "$BASE" "$REMOTE" "$LOCAL" "$MERGED"
```

The vast majority of the community agrees with that, and also tell you to add either one of these to `.gitattributes`:

```
*.unity binary
*.prefab binary
*.asset binary
```

or

```
* text=auto

# Unity files
*.meta -text merge=unityyamlmerge diff
*.unity -text merge=unityyamlmerge diff
*.asset -text merge=unityyamlmerge diff
*.prefab -text merge=unityyamlmerge diff
```

Neither of which work. I found many different alternatives to the blocks of code above. I looked for days, wasted a whole weekend even. Nothing will work and I can't find any current information on the matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows 10 using Unity 2019.3+ and a current version of Git, this was the only way I could get it to work.

### mergespecfile.txt

First, add the following entries into the `mergespecfile.txt` to allow Unity's Smart Merge to use the diff tool of your choice. I'm using Meld here. Note that `--auto-merge` is optional. The way I understand it is that it will skip prompting you for a merge.

**File Location** - Windows:
`C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\<unity version>\Editor\Data\Tools`

**File Location** - Mac:
`/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/<unity version>/Unity.app/Contents/Tools`

```
unity use "%programs%\Meld\meld.exe" "%l" "%r" "%b" "%d"
prefab use "%programs%\Meld\meld.exe" "%l" "%r" "%b" "%d"
* use "%programs%\Meld\meld.exe" "%l" "%r" "%b" "%d"
```

---

### .gitattributes

Next add this to the `.gitattributes` of your repo. Any file type you specify here will be run through Unity's Smart Merge. Anything **NOT** listed here will default to Git's auto-merge in where you can run `git mergetool` to invoke our chosen diff tool for the merge.

```
# Macro for Unity YAML-based asset files.
[attr]unityyaml -text merge=unityyamlmerge diff

# Unity files
*.meta unityyaml
*.unity unityyaml
*.asset unityyaml
*.prefab unityyaml
```

---

### .git/config

Lastly, and this was the worst part to figure out, add the following to your `.git/config`. This file is very picky about how syntax is used. And contrary to the majority of the documentation, it seems like using a merge driver is the only way to get this to trigger.

Make sure to change the filepath's to match your version/operating system, and change the merge/diff tool to whichever one you prefer.

```
[merge "unityyamlmerge"]
    driver = 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.3.14f1/Editor/Data/Tools/UnityYAMLMerge.exe' merge -p \"$BASE\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$MERGED\"
    name = Unity SmartMerge (UnityYamlMerge)
    recursive = binary
[diff]
    tool = meld
[difftool "meld"]
    path = C:/Program Files (x86)/Meld/meld.exe
[merge]
    tool = meld
[mergetool "meld"]
    path = C:/Program Files (x86)/Meld/meld.exe
    prompt = false
```

---

### UPDATE - 9/23/2021

As of Unity 2021.1.21f1 and these settings continue to work as expected.

Comment: I doubt if the custom merge driver `unityyamlmerge` takes effect at all. According to [docs on git-scm](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_defining_a_custom_merge_driver), the `merge.*.driver` expects a command template with this syntax: `executable %O %A %B %L %P`, not this: `executable $BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED`, and it *insists* to read the exit code where 0 means clean merge.

Guess an ill-formed value like one that evals to literally `UnityYAMLMerge.exe merge -p "$BASE"...` will always get exit code 1 and effectively just propagates the merge candidates to the next merge driver.

Comment: Good find! So does that mean the custom driver should be defined like: `driver = 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.3.14f1/Editor/Data/Tools/UnityYAMLMerge.exe' merge -p \"%0" \"%A\" \"%B\" \"%L\" \"%P\"`?

I moved to Plastic SCM a while back so I can't test this myself.

Comment: As the `%A`s have their respective meanings, it may be translated to like `driver = \".../UnityYAMLMerge.exe\" merge -p \"%O\" \"%B\" \"%A\" \"%A\"` according to the doc: "The merge driver is expected to leave the result of the merge in the file named with `%A` by *overwriting* it" (so `$MERGED` = `%A` here). But there's still problem: Unity says we cannot `trustExitCode` of the tool but git expects the opposite.